# MobileVLCKit always stop when Playing FB Live Video

Tags: ios, swift, vlc, vlckit

Im using MobileVlcKit and I tried to play live videos from fb live_videos api.
When i tried it to play using vlc software on my mac, it play smoothly.
But when I play it using MobileVlcKit, it always stops.

you can try it by making live on FB using OBS software.

then go to this graph API explorer URL.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Flive_videos%3Ffields%3Ddash_preview_url%2Chls_preview_url%2Clive_views%2Ccreation_time%2Cstatus%2Ctitle%2Cdescription%2Coverlay_url%2Cvideo%2Cpermalink_url%2Cdash_ingest_url%26limit%3D1&version=v8.0

then get "dash_preview_url"

and use it on VLC ios.

the bug also encounter on the VLC app from App Store.

Comment: Please share full logs

Comment: cant put logs, and cant insert pastebin link. don't know why.

but u can check this link. https://pastebin.com/raw/Lr6EjKgQ